Slurm IO error, could not open stdoutfile
I am new to Slurm. I have set it up in the cluster and on some nodes of a partition, the job runs perfectly fine but some other nodes of the same partition, the jobs do not run. They get cancelled the moment I submit them.
When I ssh into the node on which the jobs fail and look at the slurmd.log I see:
[2024-08-30T01:49:30.986] [43095.batch] error: Could not open stdout file /data/vmahajan/larchtest/slurm-43095.out: No such file or directory
[2024-08-30T01:49:30.986] [43095.batch] error: _fork_all_tasks: IO setup failed: Slurmd could not connect IO
[2024-08-30T01:49:30.987] [43095.batch] get_exit_code task 0 died by signal: 53
[2024-08-30T01:49:30.989] [43095.batch] done with job

I can only conclude that Slurm is not able to write the out file, but I fail to understand why so only on some nodes it fails to do so.

The error message states that /data/vmahajan/larchtest is either not a directory, or not accessible by the program/daemon which produced that log. Create the directory if necessary, fix ownership and permissions and try again.

Explore your Mount/Read/Write/Execute problems with https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld, a bash script to show the permissions, mount options along the path to an object or objects.
